# a photo or a snapshot

Tags: grammar

There's a Polaroid photo in the album, and I want to ask the owner about the person in it.
Can I ask him: "Who's that man in the snapshot (shot)?, or I should ask "Who's that man in the picture (photo)?"
Thanks in advance, Victor.

Comment: You can use any of them, except "shot" perhaps, but the simplest and clearest choice would be "photo".

Comment: Hi Victor, welcome to English Language & Usage (EL&U), which is "a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". You may not be aware of another site, [ELL.se], which might be very useful for you; it provides a "library of detailed answers to every question about learning the English language." For further information about what's expected here on our EL&U site, see **[Ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of nuance.  A [*snapshot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=define+snapshot), or just *snap*, is a photograph that has been taken quickly and / or informally.

While a *photograph* is any image taken by a camera, *snapshot* implies a lack of planning over framing or composition.  It is more opportunist.

It it not a derogatory term, a snapshot is not necessarily of any lower quality.

In your example of pictures in an album, it is likely that either term will do.

Comment: Plus, snapshot sounds a little old-timey, at least to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys, for your really quick replies to my question. And my special thanks are to Max Williams. I used to think that the reduction of the word "snapshot" is "shot", and not "snap". Now I know.